# Keeping database in sync with code

Tags: sql, deployment

I have been working in a few projects and noticed that as the software is getting developed, the database usually needs to evolve in the same manner. I have seen this handled in different ways, but they all look kind of like this:

- There is a file called SCRIPTS_TO_DEPLOY.
- When you need to do any kind of database change, then create a file called $TASK_$DESCRIPTION_$NUMBER.sql. Put it in a pre-defined folder.
- Add $TASK_$DESCRIPTION to the last line of SCRIPTS_TO_DEPLOY
- Execute a script that will apply all scripts to the database in the proper order.

I have two questions. 1) Does this seems like a good idea or do you have any better suggestion? 2) Feels like somewhat overkill to build scripts for this every time I start a new project. Is there some tool that can help me out perhaps?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a big challenge.  Your approach seems reasonable.

Comment: To be on the safe side, you should also have rollback scripts to be able to quickly revert to the previous version (deployment issue, big bug occurring with prod data only etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most companies and in all big projects people use it similar to you. Manually. However if you are looking for automatization you can try:

- [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)
- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)

I'd personally recommend flyway. Farily easy to set up, and works as expected.

Comment: Took a look at both of them. Liquibase could work but Flyway seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use liquibase which is for this purpose. Maintain a liquibase xml file which will track all your required changes and modify your build to execute the liquibase file automatically

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to have a look at [Liquibase](https://github.com/liquibase)

It's a sort of tool that helps managing and applying database schema changes.

I don't know what kind of software you're talking about, for java based projects, it can easily be integrated within.